# Оптимизация Trie

Tags: c++, массивы

Решил заменить медленный поиск под двухмерному массиву на Trie. В результате объем используемой памяти вырос с 7,6Мб до 43!

Как элемент массива я использую:

```
template<class TrieListEl>
class TrieListElProto/* : public OMatrixT<TrieListEl>*/{
public:
    TrieListEl *_a, *_e; // up, end
    TrieListEl *_p, *_n; // prev, next
    TrieListEl *_l, *_r; // left, right

    unsigned char key, use;
    //MString val;

    TrieListElProto(){
        _a = 0; _e = 0;
        _p = 0; _n = 0;
        _l = 0; _r = 0;

        key = 0;
        use = 0;
    }

    //void SetItem(TrieListEl &t){}

};
```

Плюс переменная для хранения значения.

_a, _e - указатели на следующий уровень массива.
_p, _n - указывают на следующий элемент на этом уровне.
_l, _r - указывают на следующий уровень имени ключа.
key - символ ключа.
use - указывает на конечный символ в имени ключа.

Я решил, что хочу Trie, прикинул как оно должно быть и сделал. Результат меня совсем не устраивает. Есть другие реализации, позволяющие использовать меньше памяти? Какие есть варианты по оптимизации моего решения?.

Comment: Вы бы озвучили что есть поиск по двумерному массиву? Структуру данных следует выбирать исходя из задач которые планируется решать. Если выбран двумерный массив - то в первую очередь нужен быстрый доступ к элементу по двум индексам.

Comment: Имелся в виду динамический массив для разбора JSON. Да, я не уверен, что выбрал правильную структуру данных, но вопрос не в этом.

Comment: Начните с четкого описания решаемой задачи и  с выбора правильной  структуры данных. JSON это   структура с множественной вложенностью. Вы делаете поиск ключа в JSON при неизвестном уровне вложености?

Comment: Задача описана - оптимизировать Trie. В JSON поиск идет в основном по первым двум уровням вложенности, по остальным тоже ищет, но гораздо реже.

Comment: Битый час пытаюсь понять как работает Ваш поиск. Из предоставленной информации выплывает, что у Вас более 650K элементов (при размере указателя 8 байт). При том размер `MString` 12 байт. Естественно не учтено выделение динамической памяти самим классом `MString`. В текущем виде `TrieListElProto` вносит максимум 64 байта дополнительных расходов. Сложно придумать намного более компактный вариант. В классическом варианте при использовании контейнера `std::map<char, TrieListElProto*>` накладные расходы 48 байт на каждый узел, без учета требуемого блока памяти под данные для std::map.

Comment: Указатель 4 байта. Размер элемента - 7*4(структура выше) + 8(данные) = 36 байт. Итого: порядка 1200К элементов. То есть std::map будет использовать меньше памяти? Каким образом?

Answer (score 2):

Оптимизировал, использовав два байта валяющихся без дела: `unsigned int key : 24, use : 8;`   Ключ стал длинной в три байта и занимаемый объем данных уменьшился в 2,45 раза, до 17,5 мегабайт. Это уже приемлимые цифры.

Полагаю в алгоритме Trie основным моментом является длинна ключа, влияющая на занимаемую память и скорость поиска.

Также полагаю, что можно оптимизировать расход памяти за счет использования нескольких типов ячеек, но это тема для исследования.